# What does "a value that lies z or more standard deviations above the expected value" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, mathematics, adverbial-phrases

This phrase came from the book *Understanding Probability* written by Henk Tijms. The original sentence is:

> the probability that a normally distributed random variable will take on a value that lies z or more standard deviations above the expected value is equal to 1 − Φ(z) for z > 0, as is the probability of a value that lies z or more standard deviations below the expected value.

I don't understand what *lies* means in this context. I have checked The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, and Webster's online; none of their explanations refer *lie* as a transitive verb. How can it used with *z or more standard deviations*, which is obviously a noun phrase?

**Could anyone explain to me:**

1. What does the sentence mean?
2. The grammar underlying this sentence? Am I right that the *lie* used here is actually a transitive verb?

Comment: I have added the lower case *phi* to your quotation. If φ is not the correct *phi*, please copy and paste the appropriate version in: ϕ Φ . If you wish to find special characters not on your keyboard in the future, you can use the program *character map* (Windows and Ubuntu have this; I don't know about Macs, other Linux distros or mobile devices) or search for the name of the character, then copy and paste.

Comment: It's the uppercase one, I reedit the question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, *z or more standard deviations* is a measure of distance. You're right about its composition but not about its usage; it's a noun phrase but *lies* is still intransitive. The phrase quantifies *above the expected value* rather than functioning as the object of *lies*. The entire clause *z or more standard deviations above the expected value* acts as an adverb to modify *lies*; it tells us *precisely where* the value *lies*.

Here's a break down and subsequent simplification.

> [A value that]<sup>1</sup> [lies]<sup>2</sup> [z or more standard deviations]<sup>3</sup> [above the expected value]<sup>4</sup>.

1. The subject; let's simplify by replacing this with *the city*.
2. The verb.
3. How far; let's simplify by replacing this with *50 kilometres*.
4. Where; let's simplify by replacing this with *away*.

Now, the sentence becomes:

> The city lies 50 kilometres away.

The grammar is exactly the same. *50 kilometres away* is an adverbial clause telling us where *the city lies*.

Answer (score 1):

Of the [*Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary's* definitions](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/lie_1), the fourth one is most applicable:

> 4 [intransitive]
>   + adverb/preposition
>   (of a town, natural feature, etc.) to be located in a particular place
>   *The town lies on the coast.*

When the values and distribution are plotted, such as on a histogram, a value can be said to *lie* somewhere on the plot.  The use of *lie* implies some kind of visualization.

You can parse the sentence as

> - **Subject:** The probability
>
>   - **Subordinate clause:** that
>
>     - **Subject:** a normally distributed random variable
>     - **Verb:** will take on
>     - **Object:** a value
>     - **Subordinate clause:** that
>
>       - **Verb:** lies
>       - **Adverbial phrase:** *z* or more standard deviations
>       - **Prepositional phrase:** above the expected value
> - **Verb:** is
> - **Adjective:** equal
> - **Prepositional phrase:** to 1 − φ(*z*)
> - **Prepositional phrase:** for *z* > 0
> - …

The verb *lie* is intransitive: its complement is a prepositional phrase ("above the expected value").

---

From a technical viewpoint, the sentence is much more complex than it needs to be.  I would probably rephrase it as

> The probability that a normally distributed random variable will take on a value ≥ *z*, where *z* is the number of standard deviations above the expected value, is 1 − φ(*z*).  By symmetry, the probability of a value *z* or more standard deviations below the expected value is also 1 − φ(*z*).

Comment: I realize I'm nitpicking semantics, but your amended version changes the meaning of the calculation with the statement *random variable will take on a value ≥ z* (only in the first sentence; the second matches the original's meaning). The random variable is a data point and not bounded by or compared to z, which is the number of standard deviations. Consider the simple case with expected value = -1000, z = 1, φ(1) = 0.5, standard deviation = 2. P(RV ≥ 1) [your  statement] is effectively zero; P(RV ≥ -998) [the original] = 0.5.

Comment: Thank you, It's really difficult to decide which answer to accept, but I had an vague understanding on the sentence already, and Esoteric's answer is more about the grammar, so I'll accept his answer.